# High TIME_WAIT and Unable to get return job id from salt minion

Tags: tcp, ubuntu-14.04, salt-stack

On salt master(Ubuntu 14.04):

```
# salt '*' test.ping or execute some state files,
```

I can see the screen hangs up like below message and can't get the job id return from the minion.

```
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: ranjith1.times.com
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /root/.saltrc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PUB socket URI: /var/run/salt/master/master_event_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PULL socket URI: /var/run/salt/master/master_event_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new AsyncZeroMQReqChannel for ('/etc/salt/pki/master', 'ranjith1.times.com_master', 'tcp://192.168.233.3:4506', 'clear')
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new IPCClient for path: /var/run/salt/master/master_event_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded local_cache.get_load
[DEBUG   ] Reading minion list from /var/cache/salt/master/jobs/58/763acd820353b8a744c7a7167c62f2/.minions.p
[DEBUG   ] get_iter_returns for jid 20161007154243656981 sent to set(['gr-test.foreman.in']) will timeout at 16:07:43.662608


# netstat shows,

Every 2.0s: netstat -antp | grep 4506

                                                                                                       Fri Oct  7 15:37:18 2016

tcp        0      0 192.168.233.3:4506      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1591/python
tcp        0      0 192.168.233.3:34619     192.168.233.3:4506      TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.233.3:34620     192.168.233.3:4506      TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.233.3:34622     192.168.233.3:4506      TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.233.3:34621     192.168.233.3:4506      TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.233.3:34617     192.168.233.3:4506      TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.233.3:34616     192.168.233.3:4506      TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.233.3:34618     192.168.233.3:4506      TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.233.3:34623     192.168.233.3:4506      TIME_WAIT   -
```

changed the below values from:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle
0
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse
0
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
60
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
32768   61000
```

to:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
15000   65000
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
30
```

but still i can see the time_wait, kindly suggest what else need to do on server side(ubuntu) or in the salt-master configuration to short this issue.

Comment: TIME_WAiT is normal, not a problem, and half a dozen of them is nothing to worry  about either,

Comment: Okay, but i can't receive the 'return job id from the salt minion' after "[DEBUG   ] get_iter_returns for jid 20161007154243656981 sent to set(['gr-test.foreman.in']) will timeout at 16:07:43.662608",                                                                                         Once i restart the salt-minion, it will again normal for next two state file execution and again hangs up with the above message

Comment: I have updated the vales: gather_job_timeout: 1500
timeout: 1500
worker_threads: 20 in Master config file, Need to fine tune the setting so kindly share the config changes what need to do further on the salt master config.

Comment: Is it possible that master (or may be physical host or networkhardware) drops the connections on the side of master? it's quite strange that minion tries to establish the connection on the every next port (34616, 34717 etc.) - I would suggest that this shows that minion (the client side) fell into reconnection state.